# Setting response status for uncaught exception handler in Roo

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-roo, jspx

I have a Roo application with standard mvc setup.

If I throw exception from my controller I get nicely rendered stack trace and status code 200 on client side.

I found that it is handled by error page defined in `web.xml` as:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/uncaughtException</location>
</error-page>
```

`uncaughtException.jspx` is:

```
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <spring:message var="title" code="error_uncaughtexception_title" htmlEscape="false" />
  <util:panel id="title" title="${title}">
    <h2>${fn:escapeXml(title)}</h2>
    <p>
      <spring:message code="error_uncaughtexception_problemdescription" />
    </p>
    <c:if test="${not empty exception}">
      <p>
        <h4>
          <spring:message code="exception_details" />
        </h4>
        <spring:message var="message" code="exception_message" htmlEscape="false" />
        <util:panel id="_message" title="${message}" openPane="false">
          <c:out value="${exception.localizedMessage}" />
        </util:panel>
        <spring:message var="stacktrace" code="exception_stacktrace" htmlEscape="false" />
        <util:panel id="_exception" title="${stacktrace}" openPane="false">
          <c:forEach items="${exception.stackTrace}" var="trace">
            <c:out value="${trace}" />
            <br />
          </c:forEach>
        </util:panel>
      </p>
    </c:if>
  </util:panel>
</div>
```

How do I change the responce code to something different than 200 ?

Is this possible to somehow set it in `uncaughtException.jspx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solves this by setting `defaultStatusCode` on `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` in `webmvc-config.xml`.

Example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultStatusCode">
        <value>500</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Any tips for this error? `The prefix "p" for attribute "p:defaultErrorView" associated with an element type "beans:bean" is not bound.`